# How to connect terminals like Ground Lugs and Feed-throughs?

Tags: rf, connector

[image: RF equipment housing]

Feed-throughs, ground lugs, and similar terminals are often found on RF test equipment. What is the standard way to connect these to wires-- wrap stranded wire and solder? Is there a part that assists in making a repeatable and robust connection?

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't RF connections, they're power and control.  In fact, the feed-throughs are specifically designed to block RF.

If you're making a permanent connection, I wouldn't be afraid to wrap a wire around and solder it.  If it's not permanent, clip leads will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't intend to say they were RF terminals. What I mean is that a wrapped and soldered wire is not a production friendly process... I'm looking for a standard socket or means of attaching wires. My leading idea is an accessory PCB that translates the connections to a standard wire harness socket.

Comment: Wrapped and soldered is the usual approach for those terminals, and I would worry about what the plating is is using a push on connector, but that said, mill-max may well have something? A PCB would work, but that earth stud will likely prove 'interesting'.